# gedit "cannot open display" , on remote computer , using ssh - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: xorg, ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I run a graphical application on a remote server when logged in  through ssh?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175686/how-do-i-run-a-graphical-application-on-a-remote-server-when-logged-in-through)

I am getting the following error message when using `ssh` to log into a remote machine:

> gedit: cannot open display

I am using ssh in - Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Did you set the DISPLAY properties properly?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this post, since the dupe is about forwarding to *Windows*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You simply need to ssh to your remote machine with `ssh -X`

```
ssh -X -l root your-machine-name
```

Once Logged in  you just start gedit or any other program of your choice from command line.

Comment: The performance may not be too great. If you are working over SSH it is recommended to use a CLI editor like [`nano`](http://askubuntu.com/q/54221/6969) (easier to use) or `vim` (more advanced but also more difficult).

Comment: Thanks - the problem was only that I used a small 'x' and not the capital 'X' !