# Sublime Command not working in SSH server on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ssh

I want sublime text editor open via `sublime` command, i've all ok for install sublime text 2, but when type `sublime` in terminal then showing me error, see below, anyone know how i can fix this ?

```
root@tmdwc:~# sublime
(sublime:22192): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Comment: Sorry, wrong link. Try this: http://askubuntu.com/q/180893/158442

Answer (score 0):

If you download `sublime text 2` from [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/2), you will get `Sublime Text 2.0.2.tar.bz2`

After unpacking archive with command

```
tar xfvj Sublime\ Text\ 2.0.2.tar.bz2
```

you will get directory `Sublime Text 2`, go to dir

```
cd  /path_to_dir/Sublime Text 2
```

and start text editor with command

```
./sublime_text
```

If you want to start text editor only with command `sublime` create sim link in `/usr/bin`

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo ln -s /path_to_dir/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text sublime
```

This link will allow to run text editor with command `sublime`

First part of problem is solved.

Exporting `X Display` via ssh you can have with option `-X`

```
ssh -l username ssh_server -X
```

With this command probably you will get your text editor in you display.

Comment: username means  `root@tmdw` ? and ssh_server ? @2707974

Comment: you also can use command in format `ssh root@tmdw -X`. In command `ssh -l username ssh_server -X`, `-l` - mean login name on server. command `ssh root@tmdw -X` is the same like `ssh -l root tmdw -X`

Comment: `root@tmdwc:~# ssh -l root@tmdwc ssh_server -X` not working

Comment: only `ssh root@tmdwc -X` or `ssh -l root tmdwc -X`

Comment: `root@tmdwc:~# ssh root@tmdwc -X`
`root@tmdwc's password: `
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-48-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
Last login: Fri Apr 24 07:58:17 2015 from tmdwc
`root@tmdwc:~# sublime`

(sublime:27953): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: `

Comment: Ok, you change question. You do not need to `ssh` on you own pc to start some app. Do you have installed `ubuntu server` without `X`?

Comment: I'm working in SSH server and with install `lamp-server^`

Comment: Ubuntu server do not have X and can not be exported. Try another text editor. `nano`, `vi`, `pico`.