# (nautilus:9229): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Tags: ssh, nautilus

I want to open graphics of remote machine using nautilus command the program displayed nothing.

here is the error i faced when i run nautilus, am using Ubuntu 16.04 and am trying to connect Ubuntu machine 14.04 remotely. using ssh administrator@proxyno.... but i want to see the graphics of the remote machine.

```
administrator@HPC-Lab-2:/$ nautilus

(nautilus:9229): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run a graphical application on a remote server when logged in through SSH?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/175686/how-do-i-run-a-graphical-application-on-a-remote-server-when-logged-in-through-s)

Comment: Connect with `ssh -X`

Comment: I already did ssh  -X but it didn't work for me.

Comment: What are you running on the local system?

Comment: @samricho then please [edit] your question *and tell us*. If you don't explain what you are doing, we will give you suggestions that you have already tried and waste your time (and ours). So, [edit] your question, explain how you are connecting, what operating system you are connecting from and what OS you are connecting to.

Comment: Look at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the remote machine if `X11Forwarding yes` and `X11DisplayOffset` is set to any number. And after logging in, `echo $DISPLAY`.

Comment: @ridgy it works for me....